# What does a restricted picklist mean?

Tags: visualforce

I was trying to build a VF page and was using event as the standard controller.
As i was display `showas` field in the Event. It throws up an validation error :

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Show Time As: bad value for restricted picklist field: Busy".

What does restricted picklist mean? VF pages cannot use this picklist at all? Not a big deal if i cant use it for my current scenario. But would like to know what the restrictions are and why these are applied?

EDIT: I am using the field ShowAs in Event Sobject. Not sure which field this is dependent on. The documentation on Event fields http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm gives the description for this field as

> Description : 
>       Indicates how this event appears when another user views the calendar: Busy, Out of Office, or Free Time. Label is Show Time As.

Had used the following Vf code

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Event.showAs}"/>
```

This allows me to save the page but when we view the page it throws up the validation error

Comment: Could you share your code? and it is bound to a picklist sobject field, if so, what type of picklist is it, multiselect- or normal picklist? or is the picklist on your visualforce page bound to a SelectOptionList you fill from your controller?

Comment: i am using the ShowAs field in Event Object. updated the question

Answer (score 6):

## Restricted Picklists

[The documentation for API field properties has this to say:](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/access_for_fields.htm)

> Restricted picklist    A picklist that depends on the value of another
>   picklist for the values it displays.

According to this, restricted picklists are dependant picklists, i.e. the values available to the user depend on another field. Whatever the controlling field is, it will probably need to be on the page also, as it seems like you're choosing a value that's not compatible with its current value. If you do have the controlling field on the page, then change the value you've chosen.

## ShowAs Gotcha

This is where it gets interesting - the system desrcibe information for this field shows that it has no controlling field, leading me to think it's controlled elsewhere in the org setup (company information perhaps?).

## Restricted vs Dependant Conclusion (Updated Nov 2014)

Despite what the documentation linked above suggests, I think that restricted might well indicate that only specific values are allowed in the field. This could still be determined by a parent field if the field is dependant as well, but most picklists allow you to enter any value via the API/code, and I think that restricted ones do not.

Comment: How is isRestrictedPicklist different than isDependentPicklist ? and to add there's one more isPermissionable method. How are these 3 different ?

Comment: `isPermissionable` simply determines whether or not permissions can be applied to that field or not. I can't find anything for sure, but I suspect the difference between the other two might be that restricted picklists only allow specific values to be set, wheras others you can set any value (via code or API, obviously not via the UI).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @LaceySnr 's thorough documentation, this `bad value for restricted picklist field:` error will occur if you are setting a picklist value to **X** and...

1. The Sobject has recordtypes
2. The recordtype you are using for that Sobject does not include **X** as an allowed value for the picklist.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this for the `ShowAs` field by using the following Visualforce instead of an `apex:inputField`.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Event.ShowAs}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Busy" itemLabel="Busy"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="OutOfOffice" itemLabel="Out of Office"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Free" itemLabel="Free"/>
</apex:selectList>
```